# Does using printf("something") or system("echo something") cost more processing power?

Tags: c, performance

This question pertains to ANSI C. I think that it should be a simple answer...so which of these methods is the fastest? It doesn't really have anything to do with my current projects but it just came to mind one day and I didn't see the answer right away on the web...

Comment: I believe `printf` is faster. I'm trying to find a specific piece I recall, though.

Comment: There is no belief required that calling `printf` is faster than asking for the standard library to invoke a new process which will then run a command in a shell...Not a Real Question.

Comment: Depends if there's a \n at the end of the string or not. but printf is faster tahn system(echo) for sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`printf` is by far preferable, by many orders of magnitude and in every sense. It is a library function that's part of the C standard, and it makes your own program print the desired output. `system` on the other hand launches a new, separate process (something that takes a comparable eternity), and you still have to hope that your shell actually provides an `echo` command that does the same thing.

The only thing *worse* than calling `system` on `echo` would be to call `system` to invoke a compiler that compiles another program that contains `printf` and run that, I guess...

Don't use `system`.

Comment: `printf` is not only preferable, it is the only correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

`system` spawns a shell to execute your command. This means that there is a `fork()/exec()` to spawn the shell and the shell in turn calls another `fork()/exec()` to execute `echo`. Not to mention the `shell` has to search the `PATH` for `echo`, pass around environment variables etc.

Terribly, terribly slower than a function call to `printf`. This is besides the fact that `system` may fail because there is no shell, or no `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

It would has been better in this case to make comparison of what is comparable...
you can call something like a printf in system(), and not only processor is involved in the fastness.

In some specific cases, i believe that it's not impossible that a call to printf would be slower than calling a new small process (but it suppose to own a bizarre configuration processor vs hdd/memory).

In the same process, using a system_call is the fastest way to write something... (without buffer issues).

In most unix system for instance, a write call (if the only need is to write a simple string) is the fastest way.

Answer (score 0):

`system` may not be able to find the `echo` command/program ... or someone with knowledge of your code could install a malicious program named `echo` on his/her path. So, not only is `system` going to be orders of magnitude slower, it's a security risk.

If you find yourself in a situation where you have to use `system`, you should *always* fully qualify the command you're calling (e.g. `/bin/echo` or `/usr/bin/echo`).

But you should never need to use it.  Anything that you can invoke an external program to do ... you should be able to find a library (or code with which you can build a library) that you can invoke from your program to do the same thing.  And it will be much faster and safer that way.